# Microchip XC32 compiler license erroneously expiring and unable to download: `Error has occured. Please try again.404~Error:-160:`

Tags: microchip, mplabx, xc32

I have two development computers, one is Windows 11, and one is Linux Ubuntu 22.04, each with their own Microchip XC32 compiler license activated for use in the MPLAB X IDE v6.10.

Both licenses are auto-renewed and recently paid for, and worked for a while, but are no longer working. Both licenses now refuse to work, and erroneously state they are expired. Their initial 30 days or so *did* work for each of them, but their *renewals* did not. When I try to re-download either license, I get this error:

> Error has occured. Please try again.404~Error:-160:

I've tried in the Chrome, Edge, and Firefox browsers.

Here is the licensing error I get when I try to build:

> Subscription License has not been renewed - the activation server "http://keyverify.microchip.com" gave the unexpected result -160
>
> License has expired

But again, both licenses *are* recently renewed, and the payments have fully processed, and I received email confirmations for their renewals.

I just bought a 3rd license, brand new. I tried to download it. It gives the same error.

Anyone else having license problems? Is the license server down? Any known issues or solutions?

---

I've created a support ticket, emailed, and called, for two days, and have reached nobody. I will report back what I eventually find. And, I've posted on the Microchip forum here: https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5CV400000008DhMAI/t393468

Screenshot of the error when I try to download the license:

[image]

Comment: This really sounds like something you need to solve with microchip, not us

Comment: +1 for Constantine's comment. Anyway, did you try the other distribution way, via e-mail?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the Microchip licensing support line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer, in particular, answers the question **How to renew your paid Pro license when it has expired or is about to expire**.

It turns out that Microchip's license renewal server was down. Microchip said (see below):

> It was caused due to an overzealous firewall rule on our server, which blocked all incoming traffic.

### Work-around: free license

As a workaround in case this ever happens again, you can follow my instructions right now to install a permanent free license you can use in the event your pro license is expired and cannot be renewed due to the license server being down: [How do I make my Microchip MPLAB X IDE project use the free version of the XC32 compiler?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/696172/26234).

Trial and error tells me that if you have this free license installed at the same time as your paid Pro license, the IDE will try to always use your paid Pro license even if it is expired and not working. In that case, you can temporarily move your paid Pro license out of the license directory to disable it. The paid Pro license file is located here:

- Windows - `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microchip\xclm\license\microchip-1.lic`
- Mac - `/Library/Application\ Support/microchip/xclm/license/microchip-1.lic`
- Linux - `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/microchip-1.lic`

Again, just move it out of that directory, while leaving only the free `xc32fpp-1.lic` file there instead, to use the free license.

### Microchip's response to my support case

Microchip replied to my support request on 30 Dec. 2023 12:15pm with the following message:

> Hi Gabriel,
>
> We are aware of issues with the page and have reported this to the respective team.
>
> While we work through this case, you may use the attached PRO Mode workstation license.
>
> The PRO Mode license will allow you to use the compiler in PRO Mode.
>
> Download the zip file, unzip it, locate the ".bat" file; and double click on it to run the batch file (for Windows machine).
>
> Run the script corresponding to your OS, if you are using Linux or Mac.
>
> This will create a license file in the license folder on the machine and activate the compiler with PRO Mode Optimizations.
>
> Path of License directory on different OS's:
>
> - Windows 10/8/7 - `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microchip\xclm\license`
> - Mac - `/Library/Application\ Support/microchip/xclm/license`
> - Linux - `/opt/microchip/xclm/license`
>
> This will activate the compiler on your machine with PRO Mode Optimizations.
>
> Regards,
>
> [name]

The zip file they sent me includes license files for Windows, Mac, and Linux, for all 3 compilers: XC8, XC16, and XC32, which work with *any* host ID (the license files contain `hostid=ANY`) and expire on 29 Jan. 2024.

Installing the license file on Linux installed license file `microchip-1.lic` at `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/microchip-1.lic`.

On 2 Jan. 2024 10:39am they then followed up again and said:

> Hi Gabriel,
>
> The issue is now fixed. It was caused due to an overzealous firewall rule on our server, which blocked all incoming traffic.
>
> Thanks,
>
> [name]

Despite my frustration, that's pretty good support.

### How to renew your paid Microchip XC32 Compiler Pro license when it has expired or is about to expire

(and now that the license server is back up)

First off, installing the pro license they gave me above does work. It expires on 24 Jan. 2024, however, as can be seen by opening the installed license file in a text editor.

I tried putting my old Pro license file back to see if it would auto-renew, but it didn't. It doesn't work.

So, I have to re-download and re-install my paid Pro license.

##### Steps to renew your paid Pro XC32 compiler license

##### Quick summary

1. Once your license auto-renewal has been paid, go here and re-download your license: https://www.microchipdirect.com/software-products.

   1. The new license has a new expiration date built into it, so a new, renewed license file must be manually downloaded and installed every month.
2. Extract the zip file, and run the executable inside it which corresponds to your OS.

   1. The 3 license installer files are:

      ```
      linux.sh
      mac.sh
      windows.bat
      ```
   2. For Linux, that would look like this:

      ```bash
      cd path/to/extracted/dir
      chmod +x linux.sh  # make the Linux license file installer executable
      ./linux.sh         # run it (do *not* use `sudo`!)
      ```
3. Done!

   1. The new license key has been installed at `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/microchip-1.lic` on Linux, or at `C:\ProgramData\Microchip\xclm\license\microchip-1.lic` on Windows, where the `-1` part of `microchip-1.lic` is an automatically-incrementing number.
   2. On both Linux and Windows, you must delete or remove the old license files to make the latest one get used. I simply created a `DISABLED` dir at `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/DISABLED` on Linux, and `C:\ProgramData\Microchip\xclm\license\DISABLED` on Windows, and drug all of the old license files into it to "disable" them.
   3. Close and re-open the IDE.

      1. This appears to be *not required* actually, on both Linux and Windows, but is not a bad idea to do it anyway.

##### Details

1. Open your expired `microchip-1.lic` license file at the paths shown above and look for the license key in it to see which license key you are using with this license. Look for this line:

   ```
   hostid=112233445566 issued=17-nov-2023 options=1111-2222-3333-4423
   ```

   The `options` field is your license key.
2. Go here to manage your paid license subscriptions / "Software Products": https://www.microchipdirect.com/software-products. You'll have to sign in.

   Here's what I see. Find the license key which matches your license file above. I've circled mine here:

   [image]
3. Click the "Download License" button for that license.

   That will open this window. You'll see your license key in the URL at the top, and your Host ID listed under "Existing Machines".

   If your license key is `1111-2222-3333-4423`, then the URL to that window is therefore: https://www.microchipdirect.com/GetLicense.aspx?id=1111-2222-3333-4423

   [image]
4. Verify that the "Host ID" listed in the window above matches the Host ID of your machine, as shown by `xclm -hostinfo` at the command-line.

   If you use the wrong host ID, the license will fail to work in the end and you'll get this error when you try to build:

   ```
   error: MPLAB XC32 C++ license not activated
   ```

   If the "Host ID" listed in the window above matches the host ID of your machine, continue to the next step.

   If it doesn't, it means either your license file is for a different machine, *or* the `xclm` tool is showing a different Host ID this time, which is possible, because it is a buggy tool and your Host ID is really just the MAC address (with*out* the colons) of one of your several network interfaces, which can change if you use USB dongles or have an Ethernet card *and* a WiFi adapter. If that's the case, you might have to email Microchip for support to change or re-register this license key. I'm not sure. In the MPLAB X IDE you can also go to Tools --> Licenses --> Activate Workstation License, which brings you here, to **register and activate your license for the first time**, which you would have already done before: https://www.microchip.com/rlmmigrationtool/GetXCLicense.aspx. I don't know if it will let you re-register your license key here. I think it will *not*, and Microchip will have to help you.

   You can see all of your MAC addresses on your system, to see if *one* of them matches your "Host ID" shown in the browser window above, as follows:

   ```bash
   # Linux, in the terminal
   ip link show | grep ether

   # Windows, in the Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
   ipconfig /all | findstr "Physical Address"
   ```
5. In the window above, click the "Download License" button.

   This will give you a .zip file with the Host ID in its name, such as `112233445566.zip`.
6. Extract the zip file, and run the executable inside it which corresponds to your OS.

   Ex: for Linux:

   ```bash
   cd 112233445566    # change directories into the extracted dir
   chmod +x linux.sh  # make it executable
   ./linux.sh         # run it (do *not* use `sudo`!)
   ```
7. Close and re-open your IDE.

   If using Git for version control, you should also refresh the project and ensure your `.gitignore` file is configured properly. See my step where I mention "Refresh the project in the IDE", [here, for details](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/696172/26234).
8. Your XC32 Pro license file is now installed!

   You'll see it now in your license file directory. Here are the license files I now see in my `/opt/microchip/xclm/license` dir on Linux:

   ```bash
   microchip-1.lic  # my old, expired XC32 Pro license
   microchip-2.lic  # my new, valid XC32 Pro license I just installed!
   xc32fpp-1.lic    # my FREE XC32 license I installed as a work-around
   ```

   The free license allows compiling C and C++ with optimization levels `-O0` or `-O1`. For `-O2`, `-O3`, or `-Os`, you need the Pro license.

   Compilation now works, and the latest Pro license (`microchip-2.lic`) will automatically be used!

   You can now delete the old, expired license file, if you want, but there's really no need.
9. Check your license file expiration dates.

   Open each license file and look for this line:

   ```
   LICENSE microchip swxc32-cpp 1.0 27-dec-2023 uncounted
   ```

   The part just before the `uncounted` word is your license expiration date. This license expired 27 Dec. 2023.

   My new license expires 27 Jan. 2024, and the `xc32fpp-1.lic` is `permanent`, which means it never expires. It shows this:

   ```
   LICENSE microchip swxc32-fpp 1.1 permanent uncounted
   ```

### References

1. My answer: [How do I make my Microchip MPLAB X IDE project use the free version of the XC32 compiler?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/696172/26234)

### See also

1. [Microchip: How to obtain a license file](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/oxy/GUID-7A7E8B19-1D3A-4880-88ED-ACA262E1EB09-en-US-1/GUID-4F00D32A-941E-4E46-8CA4-31B1FF3A334C.html)